# Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.10

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am trying to build my project using gradle command line but it keeps throwing exceptions that

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /mnt/c/Users/USER/Documents/Projects/fdroiddata/build/com.simpledecredwidget/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Complete error is [here](https://pastebin.com/nRFuc9v4)
This is my gradle wrapper located at `$projectroot/gradle/wrapper` and this is the content of my gradle wrapper

```
#Mon Dec 28 10:00:20 PST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

I have tried all i can but it is not working, as you can see i already modified my `distributionUrl` and it keeps showing the same error and pointing to the same file, Please help me in any way you can.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `gradlew clean build` commands if you are using gradle wrapper. Because if you will use `gradle clean build` command, it will still use your local gradle, I think it is 2.10 version. That's the reason you are getting error. Use `gradlew` command and firstly it will download gradle 2.14.1 version that you defined in your .properties file and it will download the 2.14.1 distribution under C:\Users\yourusername.gradle\wrapper\dists folder. You need to see the download procedure in command line.

Comment: `./gradlew` is now working but using `gradle` still throws the error, is there a difference in them. The first time i used `./gradlew` it downloaded the gradle file, now it works fine, but the `fdroid` I'm using by default uses `gradle` so i do not know what to do about that

Comment: Could you send the new error please may be i can help for that also. Also could you please accept and upvote my answer. Thank you

Comment: Any change i made to the gradle wrapper was not considered, I think there is a general gradle wrapper some where that is been used

Comment: If you start to you gradlewrapper, you have to use it forever :) If I am not mistaken, you run `gradle clean` command again in the error. But you need to run `gradlew clean` command. From now on you need to use `gradlew` in every place you would use `gradle`. Also, could you please upvote the answer.

Comment: But the I'm using `fdroid` to run it and it is using `gradle clean` by default

Comment: I think you need to set your IDE settings to use gradlew: https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/Setting_up_FDroid_in_Android_Studio have you done this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the required version of Android Plugin for each gradle version.

If you are using gradle 4.1+, you should use plugin 3.0.0+.

> You can specify the Gradle version in either the File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or by editing the Gradle distribution reference in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file. The following example sets the Gradle version to 4.1 in the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

More information: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html